# How to get infobox from a pushpinoption inside a pushpin

Tags: javascript, html, bing-maps

I use Bing map with html5 and JavaScript.

I would like to know if it's possible to get an `infobox` from a `pushpinoption` inside a `pushpin` with JavaScript ?

I have something like this with JavaScript :

```
var location = new Microsoft.Maps.Location(latitude, longitude);

var pinInfoBox = new Microsoft.Maps.Infobox(new Microsoft.Maps.Location(latitude, longitude), { id: "Id_" + p_Data[i][0], title: desc, visible: true });

var pushPinOption = { icon: etat, width: 30, height: 50, infobox: pinInfoBox };

var pushPin = new Microsoft.Maps.Pushpin(location, pushPinOption);

map.entities.push(pushPin);
m_VehiculeArray.push(pushPin);
```

Inside an other function with JavaScript, I have access to my `pushpin` but I don't know how to retrieve `pushpinOption` and finally `infobox`. I need to read 'id' property.

Could you help me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not quite sure I understand what you're trying to do but if you think this does not answer your needs, please explain what you're trying to achieve functionnaly speaking so we can help.

Anyway, if you plan to have the possibility to retrieve the information from children properties (like Pushpin > PushpinOption > Infobox), you will have several possibilities to achieve it but one possible would be to take benefit of the possibility of extension that came with Bing Maps Ajax V7 Control, here is an example that will illustrate how to keep concrete additional properties on the Pushpin object.

**Sample code**

See the sample code that will illustrate the extension capability usage, here:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Bing Maps for Enterprise - Extension</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8" src="http://ecn.dev.virtualearth.net/mapcontrol/mapcontrol.ashx?v=7.0">
    </script>
    <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.5.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        var map = null;
        var polygon = null;

        // Extension
        if (typeof (Microsoft) !== 'undefined') {
            if (typeof (Microsoft.Maps) !== 'undefined') {
                Microsoft.Maps.Pushpin.prototype.dataObject = null,
                Microsoft.Maps.Pushpin.prototype.id = null
            }
        }

        function getMap() {

            // Initialize the map
            map = new Microsoft.Maps.Map($('#map').get(0), {
                credentials: "BINGMAPSKEY",
                center: new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.5, 2.75),
                zoom: 4,
                mapTypeId: Microsoft.Maps.MapTypeId.road,
                maxZoomLevel: 28
            });

            pin = new Microsoft.Maps.Pushpin(new Microsoft.Maps.Location(45, 2));
            pin.id = "pin-myid";
            pin.dataObject = {
                title: 'My pushpin',
                description: 'Short description'
            };
            map.entities.push(pin);
            Microsoft.Maps.Events.addHandler(pin, 'click', clickPin);
        }

        function clickPin(e) {
            if (e.targetType == 'pushpin') {
                alert(e.target.id + ' == ' + e.target.dataObject.title);
            }
        }    

    </script>
</head>
<body onload="getMap();">
    <div id="map" style="position: relative; width: 800px; height: 600px;">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**More information**

If you need any more information about the extension capabilities, see my post blog (in French) available here:

http://blogs.developpeur.org/nicoboo/archive/2012/03/23/bing-maps-for-enterprise-profitez-des-possibilites-d-extension-du-controle-ajax-v7.aspx

Comment: Thanks for your explanation and your sample. Yes it's what I need.

Comment: Perfect, don't hesitate to mark it as answered so people will be able to find a possible solution for the similar problem and if you got anymore question, feel free to ask for help here.